# Cassandra - dates before 1970

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to support dates older than 1970 in Cassandra while supporting dates operations on them? I can only see timestamps. If we need older dates should I simulate my own dates as longs or perhaps as strings?

CQL doesn't return anything when I issue the query:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE ts >= '1900-01-01 00:00:00+0000'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems to be ok with Cassandra 2.0.9:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, col1 int, ts timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (id, ts));  
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, ts) values (1, 10, '2000-02-03');  
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, ts) values (1, 20, '1960-02-03');  
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, ts) values (1, 30, '1890-02-03'); 

SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE id = 1 and ts >= '1900-01-01 00:00:00+0000' limit 10;
```

Output:

```
 col1
------
   20
   10
```

Problems in earlier versions might be related to [CASSANDRA-6395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6395) (fixed in 2.0.4), or [JAVA-264](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-264) (that was later reverted).